# Synonym for sorry, except without the apologetic meaning

Tags: synonyms

[image: I'm Sorry]

What is a word that means the same thing as "sorry", except without the meaning of apology. The image above illustrates what I mean.

Edit: Although the answers below are fine, I would like it to function in a sentence similar to "sorry". Indeed, it would be best if it could be directly substituted for the word "sorry" in a sentence. (Especially good if it's a single word.)

Comment: Related (*not* a duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/what-is-it-called-when-the-word-sorry-is-not-used-for-apologizing/28111#28111

Comment: The image clearly illustrates that the answer is _sorry_; unless what you meant to ask for was a phrasing that doesn't _also_ possibly have the apologetic meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The image is being ironic.

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, exactly. The image is a peeve at people who interpret “sorry” as being an apology when it clearly is not. In other words, _sorry_ is a word that means the same as ‘sorry’ in the non-apologetic sense.

Answer (score 2):

**That's too bad**, or, shortened to **too bad**.

The idea is that the situation is bad, but no blame for it is implied:

> **Too bad** is used to express sympathy at another's misfortune. ([WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_bad))

It can be used ironically, but if said with a sympathetic tone, its meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1):

To express sympathy, you can use "It's a shame". Meaning it's regrettable or unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the apologetic connotation of sorry, you may **feel sorry** or you may [deeply] **sympathize** [with someone].

> Example: I want you to know that I understand the way you feel and
>   sympathize with your concern for your child and your grandchildren.

Answer (score 0):

**I [really] feel for you.**

> feel for someone: to feel the emotional pain that someone else is feeling; to empathize or sympathize with someone. *I really feel for you. I'm so sorry it turned out this way*. *Fred felt for Dave, but there was nothing he could do for him.*

([**McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Feel+for))